# How to use browser.getCurrentUrl() in a protractor test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have been struggling with these lines of Protractor code today:

```
element(by.linkText("People")).click();
browser.waitForAngular();        
var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
...
```

It appears that `getCurrentUrl` always fails when placed after a `waitForAngular()` statement.

The error output is too vague:

> UnknownError: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result

So, what is the correct way to click on a hyperlink and check the new url?

---

Here are my tests:

If I `getCurrentUrl()` before the link is clicked,

```
it('can visit people page', function () {
    var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    element(by.linkText("People")).click();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

The test will pass.

If I `getCurrentUrl()` after the link is clicked,

```
it('can visit people page', function () {
    var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    element(by.linkText("People")).click();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
});
```

An error is thrown in Protractor with the `UnknownError` output above. What went wrong?

Comment: i don't see anywhere in your test where you're actually referencing your url variable. I use something like `expect( browser.getCurrentUrl() ).toContain( "contact-us" );` JK, I see it's commented out.

Comment: No I haven't reference url yet. Just a call to `browser.getCurrentUrl` breaks the test!

Comment: Have you tried a delay using `browser.sleep(2000)` then trying your `expect` block after your link click?

Comment: Why do we have to delay by `sleep`? Will `browser.waitForAngular()` do the delay?

Comment: It should by default, but I've run into so many issues with protractor that sometimes manually triggering events works better. :\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `waitForAngular()` call, *wait for the URL to change*:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    return /index/.test(url);
  });
}, 10000, "URL hasn't changed");
```

Originally suggested by @juliemr at [UnknownError: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1283).

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code works correctly

```
var handlePromise = browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
handlePromise.then(function (handles) {
    // parentHandle = handles[0];
    var popUpHandle = handles[1];

    // Change to new handle
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle).then(function() {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            console.log("URL= "+ url);
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Jim Evans on several Selenium-related posts (such as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/TgLNU631vmk)  points out that "you may not assume there's an order to the handles returned by getWindowHandles(). It's a common mistake, but the handles are explicitly not in any order." I actually used code that SO posted that did so, and lost lots of time figuring out you cannot count on that.