# How to show the current URL in protractor debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor to test my angular application.

I want to show the current URL when a `console.log` is show in the browser.
I use this for now but I don't find the solution to show the current URL.

```
afterEach(function() {
  browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog){
    var message = JSON.parse(browserLog[i].message).message.parameters[0].value;
    expect(message.indexOf("localizationService") > -1).toBe(false, 'because\n There is a I18N error somewhere.\n Please see the error above in\n >>ERROR I18Ns : \n' + message + '\n' + browser.getCurrentUrl());
  }
}
```

I just need to know what I have to use instead of `browser.getCurrentUrl()` which is returning a `Promise`

Comment: I just need to know what I have to use instead of browser.getCurrentUrl() wich is returning a promise

Comment: Is Protractor relevant here? Wouldn't `window.location.href ` do?

Comment: Window is not defined

Comment: Are you running your script in browser right? You could try `document.location.href`. Check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746566/2794702) for reference.

Comment: The code is actually in protractor.conf.js. Document is not defined too.

Comment: I see. Have you seen [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129186/how-to-use-browser-getcurrenturl-in-a-protractor-test)?

Comment: Yes they use getcurrenturl promise to compare the actual URL with an other one. In my case, I just want to display the current URL.

Comment: I need something like browser.getCurrentUrl().toString()

Comment: So to be clear: you want to execute this command within the context of the browser, but evaluate within your protractor test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the url by resolving the promise that **getCurrentUrl()** function returns and then expect your requirement. Here's how you can do it -

```
afterEach(function() {
  browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog){
    var message = JSON.parse(browserLog[i].message).message.parameters[0].value;
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
        expect(message.indexOf("localizationService") > -1).toBe(false, 'because\n There is a I18N error somewhere.\n Please see the error above in\n >>ERROR I18Ns : \n' + message + '\n' + url);
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.