# How to get current url using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129186/how-to-use-browser-getcurrenturl-in-a-protractor-test) question, and read [this](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl) documentation, but still i cannot get the url as `string` value.

I know that in `protractor`, you should use the below code to get `url`:

```
import {browser} from 'protractor'
browser.waitForAngular();    
var url = browser.getCurrentUrl()
console.log("URL is: "+url);
```

But, when i run the code in the console i have:

```
URL is: ManagedPromise::253 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

Also, the documentation specifies that the result of function is ***a promise that will be resolved with the current URL.***

But, i am wondering, why i am not able to get it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {browser} from 'protractor'
browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
    console.log("URL is: "+url);
})
```

Comment: it seems that, it never reach to `console.log`

Answer (score 2):

browser.getCurrentUrl() returns a promise.

You have to resolve the promise to get the current URL.

```
var currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
console.log(url);
return url;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you could see from [documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl) the `getCurrentUrl()` method return `!webdriver.promise.Promise.<string>`, translated to people language the method return `Promise` that contains `string`. So you need, firstly, to resolve Promise. I highly recommended to read this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) for getting understanding.
Example with `async ... await`:

```
async function pageUrl() {
   const url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
   return url;
}
```